# How to deploy an .ear file in glassfish?

Tags: deployment, glassfish

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1757/6nmni99aj/index.html

```
as-install/bin/asadmin deploy war-name
```

The docs mention this command, but where will it be deployed isn't mentioned. Does it automatically realizes in which domain it should be deployed? And in which location it should be deployed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you would do this:

```
as-install/bin/asadmin --port 4848 deploy war-name
```